# plot specific columns and rows from a file with pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data file where I want to plot specific lines of the second column. My script is as follows:

```
f=open('datafile','r')
lines1=f.readlines()[4:24]#since I want the values from the 4th to the 23rd line
lines2=f.readlines()[33:54]#I want the values from the 33rd to the 53rd line
f.close()

x1=[]
y1=[]

for line in lines1:
    p=line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[1]))#the values are in the second column
for line in line2:
    p=line.split()
    y1.append(float(p[1]))

xv=np.array(x1)
yv=np.array(y1)

plt.plot(xv,yv)
```

However, at the end I have an error saying "x and y must have same first dimension". I am not very experienced with python, could somebody advise me any alternative or let me know what am I doing wrong? How could I extract only those rows with a different way?

I want to plot x= column 2 from row 4 to row 25 against y=column 2 from row 33 to row 54.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,

Gio

Comment: In the text you refer to wanting to plot certain rows, but you're using a different range of rows in the code: [4:24] vs. "from row 4 to row 25". Also, note that lists in Python start from 0, so [4:] is starting at the fifth item in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is calling `readlines` two times.

A [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) behaves like an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Calling `readlines` will **exhaust** it. The second call will return an empty list.

You can get the list of lines once and then work with it:

```
lines = f.readlines()
lines1 = lines[4:24]
lines2 = lines[33:54]
```

Still, it looks like the lengths of the lists will differ by 1, I guess you need to correct that.

Also note that you don't need to convert lists to `numpy` arrays to plot them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Indeed, my lists differ by 1 from each other. Anyway it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and python slices:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_start, x_end = 4, 25 # get values from the 4th to the 25rd line
y_start, y_end = 33, 54 # get values from the 33rd to the 54rd line

x = np.genfromtxt('datafile', usecols=(1))
y = np.genfromtxt('datafile', usecols=(1))

x = x[x_start - 1:x_end]
y = y[y_start - 1:y_end]

print ' x=', x, '\n\n y=', y

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you know any good tutorial to read for working on data with matplotlib and numpy?

Comment: However, it seems that np.genfromtxt reads only one column. How could I split my file? It says "got one columns instead of 1"

Comment: @gioR, native numpy and matplotlib documentation are pretty damn good. :) http://matplotlib.org/contents.html http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial Also I recommend you to use matplotlib gallery (http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) if you need to solve some issue but doesn't know how to name it. And remember that google & stackoverflow is extremely powerful combination.

Comment: @gioR, np.genfromtxt reads here only one column (the second one with index 1) only because I set input param usecols=(1) at this example. Actually it's the function that reads whole file. Please, read the documentation here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html.

Comment: @gioR, ehm, sir, and one moment.. if your task solved by answers on this thread, please, can you mark one of them as 'accepted'? It will be +2 reputation for you and +15 reputation for answer's author. :) Thank you!